# Can a JAX-RS resource method return multiple images?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

We have a web application which produces 2-3 images after an algorithm is run. We want to return these images to the user. I thought the best design would be to store the images outside the project code base: in an external folder like the `/tmp` directory.

First off, do you agree with this design decision? I feel like the project code base would get bloated every time we run the algorithm. My boss wanted me to store the images inside our webapp, but I made a  good case for storing them in the `/tmp` directory.

Secondly, is it possible to return multiple images (most likely 2 or 3) in a single JAX-RS resource method? I've never seen this done, so I'm inclined to think I should write a generic resource method for returning an image given the filename.

I would really appreciate feedback on both questions. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: From my perspective, web pages have a pretty standard way of serving images (even if the client is now fancy AJAX requests). There is a single URL for a single image. I wouldn't try to deviate from that. Make your resource return the 2-3 URLs for the image locations.

Comment: Since the algorithm produces 2-3 images on every iteration, and we have to hold onto these images for at least a week, my fear is that the code base will become bloated, if we store the images inside the code base. That's why I wanted to store them in an external location. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have a web application which produces 2-3 images after an algorithm
>   is run. We want to return these images to the user. I thought the best
>   design would be to store the images outside the project code base: in
>   an external folder like the /tmp directory.
>
> First off, do you agree with this design decision? I feel like the
>   project code base would get bloated every time we run the algorithm.
>   My boss wanted me to store the images inside our webapp, but I made a
>   good case for storing them in the /tmp directory.

The design decision question is pretty opinion-based, I think. I'll give you my thoughts, but I can't say that this part is an "answer", it's just an opinion.

As I mentioned in a comment, from my perspective, web pages have a pretty standard way of serving images (even if the client is now fancy AJAX requests). There is a single URL for a single image. I wouldn't try to deviate from that.

Where you decide to host them is up to you. I'd probably use a web server such as nginx (as opposed to an application server), which is optimized for serving static content like images, js files, etc.

> I feel like the project code base would get bloated every time we run the algorithm.

This part confuses me. You are producing image files. This is just data. It isn't code and it doesn't really inflate the code base. If you mean consuming disk space where you store your code, sure, host it somewhere else.

> Secondly, is it possible to return multiple images (most likely 2 or
>   3) in a single JAX-RS resource method? I've never seen this done, so
>   I'm inclined to think I should write a generic resource method for
>   returning an image given the filename.

It's *possible* in a sense of the word. You could encode the images as text that would be used for embedded images. For example (stolen from a [page explaining embedding images in html](http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/)):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM0AAAD
 NCAMAAAAsYgRbAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5c
 cllPAAAABJQTFRF3NSmzMewPxIG//ncJEJsldTou1jHgAAAARBJREFUeNrs2EEK
 gCAQBVDLuv+V20dENbMY831wKz4Y/VHb/5RGQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ
 0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0PzMWtyaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoxtb0QGho
 aGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaMbRLEvv50VTQ9OTQ5OpyZ01GpM2g0bfmDQaL7S+ofFC6x
 v3ZpxJiywakzbvd9r3RWPS9I2+MWk0+kbf0Hih9Y17U0nTHibrDDQ0NDQ0NDQ0
 NDQ0NDQ0NTXbRSL/AK72o6GhoaGhoRlL8951vwsNDQ0NDQ1NDc0WyHtDTEhD
 Q0NDQ0NTS5MdGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGposzSHAAErMwwQ2HwRQ
 AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="beastie.png">
```

You could return that data in the JSON response object as text. I wouldn't do that, but it is an option.

I'd just return a response object that has the URLs of where to get the actual images. That makes for a cleaner API.